# YouTube player in ScrollView android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

When youtube player fragment nested in **ScrollView** I get error when rotate device to landscape:

```
YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY
```

And what is more interesting, is that the problem disappears when I remove **ScrollView**! But I can

```html
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        />
        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview should have only one child

Answer (score 0):

***YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY*** error indicates that *Playback has been stopped due to a view overlaying the player. This means that the YouTube Player has been obscured by some other view on top of it. The YouTube API can detect it and stop the Playback.

One very common reason for this to happen is when the fragment for holding the YouTube player is embedded in a scroll view. Scroll View adds additional layer of elements can be be scrolled. For.eg the  in your case. The player contained in the same declaration would detect the overlap and would eventually stop giving the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a YoutubePlayer inside of a ScrollView and it stops with this message:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.ScrollView{69b88e5 VFED.V... ........ 0,0-1794,1017 #7f0d0070 app:id/scrollview}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 21, top: 196, right: 21, bottom: -164 (these should all be positive).
```

This happens all the time when the video is not fully visible on the screen. When it is visible completely, rotating the device works fine. To me this looks like a bug in the Youtube Android Player. I made a workaround with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // This is an ugly workaround to prevent youtube from (wrongly) thinking we have an
    // overlay above the video. Having overlays is not allowed and the video would stop otherwise.
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int offset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, metrics);
    scrollView.scrollTo(0, youtubePlayer.getView().getTop() - offset);
}
```

This obviously is not a good fix, because it depends on the ratio of the video and how it is shown on your display. Also your ScrollView will be scrolled to a different place after rotation (which you could re-reset manually later on).